# How to correlate amount of occurrences of an event to an ecommerce conversion?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm developing a plugin for e-commerce sites. I need to measure how efficient it is in increasing conversions.

Can Google Analytics be used to measure the correlation between the amount of interactions with my plugin and standard conversion metrics?
(conversion rate, average purchase amount, session duration, bounce etc.)

Comment: Probably yes, but since we do not know what your plugin is doing or what it plugs into I doubt anybody will be able to assist you.

Comment: Basically I want to correlate between the amount of occurrences sent of a certain event for a specific user and the probability of purchase for that user.